# bootstrap, jQuery - cannot find the element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the value of text box to perform validation on it, but somehow my `jQuery` code gives me an error when trying to retrieve the value from it. I'm using `bootstrap` as well.

This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

This is my function:

```
$(function () {
    var year = document.getElementById('<%=txtReportYear.ClientID %>').value;
    alert(year);
});
```

This is the fragment of the code that has the text box:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtReportYear" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Year" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

However, after substituting `<%=txtReportYear.ClientID %>` with the exact id of the control `MainContent_maincontent_txtReportYear`, everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET markup is translated into HTML by the browser. You can set `ClientIDMode=Static` to  force the browser to keep the ID value that you set.